# how to define init in serializer to set all fields required=False in Django rest?

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, init, django-serializer

I have a model in which data is filled through a form in the frontend by API call. I have an update api in which all the fields are set to required=False.

I have done it in the following way:

```
class LeadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email= serializers.EmailField(required=False)
    phone = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        # fields = '__all__'
        # depth = 1

        fields = ['id','title','first_name','last_name','address','company_name',
                  'city','state','country','phone','source','mobile',
                  'email','gender','date_created','lead_status']
```

Here I have shown only four fields as `required=False` But I need this for all the fields. How to set all fields to false by writing init function here inside the serializer instead of writing every field manually?

PS I am using same serializer (the above one) for creating, listing and updating.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve this in the serializer you need to use the `extra_kwargs` Meta option. There is an example below of the usage:

```
class Meta:
    model = Lead
    # fields = '__all__'
    # depth = 1

    fields = ['id','title','first_name','last_name','address','company_name',
                  'city','state','country','phone','source','mobile',
                  'email','gender','date_created','lead_status']
    extra_kwargs = {
        'company_name': {'required': False},
        'city': {'required': False},
    }
```