# use of mixins class defined in Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

What is the actual use of Mixins class? I don't really get it. All the mixins classes like CreateModelmixin, Listmixin, etc features are already available in class-based view like ListCreateApiView.

For eg:

```
class ExampleView(ListCreateAPIView
                 DestroyAPIView,
               RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Example.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomPageNumberPagination
```

Using mixins we can do it by following:

```
class ExampleView(ListAPIView,
                     mixins.CreateModelMixin):
        queryset = Example.objects.all()
        serializer_class = ExampleSerializer
        pagination_class = CustomPageNumberPagination
```

When I check https://www.cdrf.co/ I see the methods that are available in CreateModelMixing are the following:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 
def get_success_headers(self, data): 
def perform_create(self, serializer):
```

These methods are already available in ListCreateApiView, then why Django went to create this useless class??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ListCeateAPIView` class **uses the `CreateModelMixin` mixin**. Indeed, take a look at the [*Ancestors* (Method Resolution Order; MRO) of the `ListCreateAPIView` [classy-drf]](https://www.cdrf.co/3.12/rest_framework.generics/ListCreateAPIView.html). It contains the `CreateModelMixin`.

Most `APIView`s that Django made are just an `APIView` and a bunch of mixins. These mixins define the actual behavior. The `ListCreateAPIView` (and other subclasses of the `APIView`) are just packs of mixins and the `APIView`.

This is also the use-case of a mixin: mixing in certain logic in a class. There are multiple `APIView`s that allow creating an object like a `CreateAPIView`, `ListCreateAPIView` and the `ModelViewSet`. Instead of implementing the same logic in all these classes, or work with inheritance of a base-class that would only be *linear*, one can mix it in all hierarchies by making use of a mixin that implements the logic.

It is also useful to work with these mixins if you for example want to construct a subclass of an `APIView` yourself that does something sophisticated, and at the same time mix in logic for the `create` handle that does not do such sophisticated things.

If you use a mixin however, that is usually written *before* the base class, so:

```
#              mixin first 🖟
class ExampleView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, ListAPIView):
    # …
```

this is necessary since mixins can often override existing methods, and thus the mixin should take precedence in the MRO over the base class.

Comment: thanks, you made it clear that it is because of apiview used with createmodelmixin, that i was able to use createapiview....But is there any proper use case to use only createmodelmixin without  use of listapiview and other classes.??

Comment: Yes, if you want your view to implement only part of the ModelMethod. For instance, if you want it to be only Create and Delete, you would inherit from : Create,Delete, Generic.
Just to add on the answer, Mixins aren't tied to views, but it can be quite tricky sometimes, for instance : https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/8360 means that some inheritance with DRF will not work as you intend.

Comment: @Reactoo: if you want to only combine the create and list functionality, no, then you use a `ListCreateAPIView`. The idea to expose mixins is simply to make it more useful to reuse the implemented logic. But here a `ListCreateAPIView` is likely sufficient.

Comment: Hello @WillemVanOnsem I have so many unanswered questions. You are the only one that I see is capable of answering them. For eg : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70952311/how-to-define-init-in-serializer-to-set-all-fields-required-false-in-django-rest